# I can not publish a workbook contains spatial data on TABLEAU SERVER

Tags: tableau-api, spatial-data

I created a map using Tableau Desktop 2018.2.4, that works works well in the Desktop version of Tableau. However, when I try to publish the workbook to Tableau Server 10.2.3, I receive an error saying that the spatial data does not exist in my database. What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a version compatibility issue between Desktop and Server versions. Were you prompted to downgrade the workbook version from 2018.2.x to 10.x?

For more information, read [this article](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/desktopdeploy/en-us/desktop_deploy_compatibility.htm) in the Tableau Deployment Guide.

Answer (score 0):

There Two way

**1st**

Edit your workbook in notepad and replace the version of the tableau server

**2nd**

You will find the downgrade option from tableau desktop from file toolbar.
[image: tabelau]